# Node.js - how to send a file system path in HTML response to view the files in browser

Tags: html, node.js, http, express

I have this situation where I want to return content from my nodejs express controller which has a file system link to view logs in browser.

When I click this link there is no action it doesn't show me the logs in browser for the file path specified in the href link, but the same works if I copy the path directly in browser address bar.

**Code:**

```
'use strict';
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {
    var output = exec('node --version');
    fs.writeFile('logs/output.log', output.toString(), function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("done");
    });
    res.send('<a href="file:///C:/myapp/logs/" target="_blank">Visit logs</a>');
};
```

When I click 'Visit logs' in browser it should list all files in logs folder in browser but this is not working. If I copy 'file:///C:/study/myapp/logs/' and paste in address bar I can view all files in browser.

Comment: Client and server are running on the same system ?

Answer (score 0):

There are things needed to understand.

1. The file linked using `file:///` will / may not be found if the `html` file/page is opened on another system(client).
2. Assuming that you're running this html page using a http web server and in the browser, you actually open - `http://host:port/your-web-page.html` or similar link. If this is the case, you won't be able to link and open files using `file:///` because of security implemented. You would be able to open files links only from a `file:///` url.

Because of the 2nd point, most modern browsers will not allow linking. If you want a workaround(not suggested though), please check here - [Link to Local files](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)

Answer (score 0):

To view your **logs file** in browser, you need first read file in server side, and then send it to response. [Example github repo](https://github.com/Mestafor/example-show-logs-in-browser)

Example:

```
// Show list
fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, 'logs'), (err, data) => {
  if(!err && data.length > 0) {
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<a href="/">Back</a> </br><hr>');
    res.end(
      data.reduce((str, fileName) => {
        str += `<a href="/logs/${fileName}">${fileName}</a></br>`
        return str;
      }, '')
    );
  } else {
    res.writeHead(500);
    res.end();
  }
});
```